# Square Connect with node/angular

Tags: angular, payment, square

I am trying to integrate the Square Online payments into my web app. Here is the error I am getting:

> Uncaught FormNotReadyError: Cannot call SqPaymentForm#requestCardNonce
>   before SqPaymentForm is ready.

I have not been able to really find anything with integrating Square online payments into Angular, and I am still fairly new to angular/node. Thanks

payment.html

```
<div id="form-container">
  <div id="sq-ccbox">
    <form id="nonce-form" novalidate action="process-payment" 
 method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
         <div class="third">
          <div id="sq-expiration-date"><input type="text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
          <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
        </div>
       <div class="third">
         <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" 
    onclick="onGetCardNonce(event)">Pay $1.00</button>
  <!--
    After a nonce is generated it will be assigned to this hidden input 
field.
  -->
  <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
</form>
  </div> <!-- end #sq-ccbox -->
 </div> <!-- end #form-container -->
```

payment.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  declare var SqPaymentForm: any;

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-payment',
     templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css']
   })
    export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {


      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
     const applicationId = 'sandbox-sq0idp-HgQsUszzlyjKUGnaq6Ps0Q';

// onGetCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay $1.00" button is clicked
     function onGetCardNonce(event) {
// Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
event.preventDefault();
// Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
 // tslint:disable-next-line: no-use-before-declare
 paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}

// Create and initialize a payment form object
    const paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
 // Initialize the payment form elements
 applicationId,
 inputClass: 'sq-input',

// Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
 inputStyles: [{
fontSize: '16px',
lineHeight: '24px',
padding: '16px',
placeholderColor: '#a0a0a0',
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
}],

// Initialize the credit card placeholders
 cardNumber: {
     elementId: 'sq-card-number',
     placeholder: 'Card Number'
},
 cvv: {
     elementId: 'sq-cvv',
    placeholder: 'CVV'
 },
 expirationDate: {
     elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
     placeholder: 'MM/YY'
 },
 postalCode: {
     elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
     placeholder: 'Postal'
 },

 // SqPaymentForm callback functions
 callbacks: {
     /*
     * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
     * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
    */
     cardNonceResponseReceived (errors, nonce, cardData) {
     if (errors) {
         // Log errors from nonce generation to the browser developer 
  console.
        console.error('Encountered errors:');
 // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
             console.error('  ' + error.message);
         });
        alert('Encountered errors, check browser developer console for 
 more details');
         return;
     }

     alert(`The generated nonce is:\n${nonce}`);
    // Uncomment the following block to
    // 1. assign the nonce to a form field and
    // 2. post the form to the payment processing handler

   ( document.getElementById('card-nonce') as HTMLInputElement).value = 
nonce
     ( document.getElementById('nonce-form') as HTMLFormElement).submit();

    alert('The generated nonce is:\n${nonce}');
    }
}
});
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi Chad, I'm not familiar with Angular myself, but it sounds like the Payment Form is simply not ready/loaded. Could you try calling `paymentForm.build()` when the page finishes loading (or sometime before the calling `requestCardNonce`?) Please let me know if that doesn't work though.

Comment: Yes I will look at the docs again and try that in a bit. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Yes, the paymentForm.build() did help. Thank you. Now, I just need to figure out how to tie in node to it. I have it setup like they do on the documentation on squares site. I'm just not sure how to bring it together correctly.

Comment: Glad the build function helped! Let me know if you need additional help. Feel free to join the buildwithsquare Slack community to get help from Square folks and other developers who are using Square: https://squ.re/2Hks3YE