# Without SqPaymentForm how to call cardNonceResponseReceived with card data?

Tags: angular7, square-connect

I am working on Square Payment gateway integration in angular 7. I want to request card_nonce using information stored in database. Can I directly request for card_nonce without using SqPaymentForm?

In my angular app multiple step form, I am get the token on last step. But payment form in another component. How it is prossible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to request a nonce, you must use the Square Payment Form. There is no other way to request a nonce.

Regarding your second question: please take a look at a recent Angular Square Payment Form question and it should help out: [Square Connect with node/angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56587001/square-connect-with-node-angular)